# How do I find city ordinances online?

Tags: local-ordinance

How would I be able to find city ordinances online for: **Millbrook, AL 36054, USA** ?

Comment: There is a chance your municipality does not have them online as well. In that case you need to go to town center/city hall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Google search turned up this link:

https://www.municode.com/library/al/millbrook/codes/code_of_ordinances

Comment: Municode is even better than the books b/c it's updated at the least monthly (weekly in my municipality), and ordinances change often since all it takes is a vote of the City Council (of alderman, or whatever your form of local gov't is). Once they submit to the state for approval, Municode will update (assuming its approved). Good Call @ Mowzer